# Multisite with content sharing

Tags: organic-groups, multi-sites, domain-access

The last couple of days I have been looking into Drupals multisite with content sharing. Got some great information like http://palantir.net/blog/multi-headed-drupal and http://munich2012.drupal.org/program/sessions/multi-headed-drupal

It gives me a good idea of the options I have building a multisite and content sharing setup. As I am quite new to Drupal I am trying to get input on my setup and the architecture that is required to build it. I will briefly explain the architecture and then the options I think will be suited for this.

**Basic setup**
The basic setup is as follows. There will be 1 global website with an own admin/editor. Next to the global site there will be 10 regional websites with their own regional admins/editors. The regional websites will have content in their own language, but in the CMS there is an option to translate the content to English.

**Global website**
The global website will be a 1 page website and it displays content (English) from the regional websites. Content that needs to be curated by the global content-editor.

**Regional websites**
The regional websites are all the same (pages , nodes, content types) except for some different styling and logo's.

**Access levels**
The global admin can access all the websites, this can be using other logins or preferably an own global account. The regional admins/editors can only access and edit their own site.

From the information I have so far, this will require a combination of Domain Access and Organic groups but I am not sure if this is going to work.
My main concern is combining a global home with the regional websites and push content to the global home. Not only pushing but the the global editor will need to approve content before displaying it on the global home.

Does anyone know if we can build such a setup with Drupal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently this isn't to common with Drupal. Any ideas on other approaches?

Comment: Your approach looks good. Start doing it and come back with more direct questions. We can't design it from the ground up for you.

Answer (score 1):

I might think about using a login mechanism like OAuth (with its Connector module) or an LDAP instance so that your global admin can login to any site with the same login.

To distribute the content, I would try using a REST API from the regional sites via the Services module which supports login if content or views needs access control.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Make views from reginonal site content that global can include in some admin page.

From that page global admin can pick url of the regional content and paste it in to list of "approved content".

Build stripped custom entity-view for the content available at regional url so the global site can parse the approved content list to list of entity-views.

This wouldnt necessarily need any cross site permission integration.